# invoke default camera and save pic at user defined location which is not part of gallery

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to invoke the default device camera from my application to take picture using intent **android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE**. Everything seems to be working fine except for when i click and save a particular image it gets stored at two location

```
1. At the default camera location.
2. At the location which i am passing with intent.
```

I **just want the 2nd option** to happen and not the 1st one. I thought creating a .nomedia file in used defined location would make sure that the picture would not be listed as part of gallery but later i found that the pic is getting stored at both the location.

My relevant portion of code is:

In the Activity:

```
Intent intentCamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
try {
    tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    // place where to store camera taken picture
    photo = createTemporaryFile("picture", ".jpg", tempDir);
    photo.delete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please check SD card! Error in fetching image",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
 if (photo != null) {
           Uri mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
           Log.i(TAG, "" + mImageUri.toString());
           intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
 } 
startActivityForResult(intentCamera, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

The corresponding method.

```
public File createTemporaryFile(String part, String ext,File tempDir) throws Exception {
tempDir = new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath() +"/temp/");
if (!tempDir.exists()) {
   tempDir.mkdir();
   }
createNoMediaFile(tempDir.getAbsolutePath());
return File.createTempFile(part, ext, tempDir);
}
```

Is there a way i can avoid 1 i.e. saving the image to the default gallery location. Thanks.

Comment: I have observed same behavior in Instagram app too.

Answer (score 1):

onActivityResult returns you the Uri of Image you can retrieve the path of Image copy the image from that location and save at your desired location and after that delete that from Gallery.

Comment: I tried this onActivityResult gives me the uri for the path which i passed as intent and not the one which is part of gallery. Correct me if wrong.How do i get the uri of the image which is part of the gallery.